# Rounding decimal monetary value to penny multiples

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding

Could some one help me to find a good way to round decimal monetary values to nearest multiples of 10 cents/pennies

10.47  is 10.50

10.4366677   is 10.40

10.489999   is 10.50

I have my money value stored in a decimal variable.

Comment: Check out [Math.Round()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError- My requirement is a bit different to rounding to fractional digits. I need to round to 10 penny multiples as explained in the question

Comment: Round to 1/10th of a dollar and then output the full 2-digit fraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Math.Round and Decimal.Round both let you specify a number of decimal places to round to.  If you then want to display the value with two decimal places then you need to call ToString and specify that by using a format specifier like "c2", "n2" or "f2".

Comment: Sorry, that is not the question I am asking.

Comment: Um, that is the question you asked.  Maybe that's not the question you meant to ask but it is the one you asked.  For instance, if you do this: `decimal d = decimal.Round(10.4366677M, 1);` then `d` will contain the value 10.4.  There's no such number as 10.40 because numbers don't have trailing zeroes.  If you want to display a trailing zero then you have to specify that when you convert the number to a string, e.g. `string s = d.ToString("n2");`